# Tradingview Syntax error at input ')'. Error , v5 version Problem

Tags: pine-script

In the code below it gave the error "Syntax error at input ')'".

```
mtfatr = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf2, ta.tr(nATRPeriod))
pricetwo = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf2, close)
crofate = nATRMultip * mtfatr
TrailingMTF = pricetwo > nz(TrailingMTF[1], 0) and pricetwo[1] > nz(TrailingMTF[1], 0)? math.max(nz(TrailingMTF[1]), pricetwo - crofate): pricetwo < nz(TrailingMTF[1], 0) and pricetwo[1] < nz(TrailingMTF[1], 0)? math.min(nz(TrailingMTF[1]), pricetwo + crofate): pricetwo > nz(TrailingMTF[1], 0) and pricetwo - crofate? pricetwo + crofate:na)))
value2 =    if(pricetwo[1] < nz(TrailingMTF[1], 0) and pricetwo > nz(TrailingMTF[1], 0), 1,
        if(pricetwo[1] > nz(TrailingMTF[1], 0) and pricetwo < nz(TrailingMTF[1], 0), -1, nz(value2[1], 0))) 
color2 = value2 == -1 ? red: value2 == 1 ? green : blue
plot(multimtf ? TrailingMTF : na, color=color2, linewidth=4 , title="Tengri Supertrend MTF")
```

Comment: Thank you my friend but now existed "
Mismatched input ',' expecting ')'." error at value2 line. Can you help me again?

Answer (score 0):

The `)))` at the end of `TrailingMTF` definition is not needed.

```
TrailingMTF = 0.0
TrailingMTF := pricetwo > nz(TrailingMTF[1], 0) and pricetwo[1] > nz(TrailingMTF[1], 0)? math.max(nz(TrailingMTF[1]), pricetwo - crofate): pricetwo < nz(TrailingMTF[1], 0) and pricetwo[1] < nz(TrailingMTF[1], 0)? math.min(nz(TrailingMTF[1]), pricetwo + crofate): pricetwo > nz(TrailingMTF[1], 0) and pricetwo - crofate ? pricetwo + crofate:na
```